# how to select few lines from n lines of text from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have n lines of text in my DataFrame row, I want only few lines of text from that DataFrame row.

here's that code i have used

```
data.col_name[0]=data.col_name[0][10:100]
data.col_name[1]=data.col_name[1][10:100]
data.col_name[2]=data.col_name[2][10:100]
data.col_name[3]=data.col_name[3][10:100]
data.col_name[4]=data.col_name[4][10:100]
```

how can i do it more efficiently?

Comment: Please elaborate: do you always want these *specific* lines? What would you like to *do* with the lines (save to new dataframe, print, return, etc.)?

Comment: Ya i want that specific lines for all the rows.          I have text in each row of my dataframe , which contains 1000 lines of text. I want only 100 lines from each row of a dataframe and i want to save it in that dataframe only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try With This Code:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df['Column_Name'][i] = df['Column_Name'][i][0:100]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `iloc` in such a case. Simply you can do

```
data.iloc[10:100, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

If you want just one column at a time:

```
data.iloc[10:100, 0]
```

and so on.

**EDIT:**
If you want to slice specific column data you can use `str.slice`. Let's say I will Message column has *1000* lines of data in a single row and I will slice first *50* characters.

```
data['Message'] = data['Message'].str.slice(0,50,1)
```

OR

```
df.iloc[:, 2] = df.iloc[:, 2].str.slice(0, 50, 1)
```

Comment: Actually i want the text from that particular row in a data frame . There is 1000 lines of text in each row but i want only firt 100 lines.

Comment: What do you mean by saying 1000 lines of text in each row? You want to slice row or column?

Comment: I have 40 rows and 4 columns     and i want to peform this for all the rows of 3rd column

Comment: Thanq         data['Message'] = data['Message'].str.slice(0,50,1) worked for me.

Comment: @ANURAGSINGH then please consider of accepting the answer so others can find it easily and upvote for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

**data['Message'] = data['Message'].str.slice(0,50,1)**

this worked well for me thank you @Rarblack